# Скролл до блока с учетом высоты фиксированного меню

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте,
этим кодом я реализую скролл до блока.

```
$(document).on("click", ".scroll", function(t) {
    t.preventDefault();
    var i = $(this).attr("href"),
        e = $(i),
        s = e.offset().top;
    return $("html,body").animate({
        scrollTop: s
    }, 1e3), !1
})
```

Подскажите как изменить код, чтобы при скролле учитывалась высота фиксированного меню? Например высота меню 200px

Comment: s = e.offset().top+200;